# SQL-SSIS. Find missing numbers in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm using ssis 2008 and sql server 2012.
I have a table with column `FileNumber`. I would like to make sure all the numbers are following and there are no wholes. No missing numbers.
For example:

```
FileNumber
--------------
110
111
112
114
115
117
```

I would like the ssis to output the numbers `113` and `116` which are missing.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Ideally this would be an identity then - but I'm guessing you don't want to change any existing file numbers. Is adding a second column with identity sufficient? I guess it depends why you need it to be contiguous in the first place.

Comment: I would like to make sure that all the files were loaded to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t table(
 FileNumber int
 );

INSERT INTO @t(FileNumber) VALUES(110), (111), (112), (114), (115), (117);

SELECT t1.FileNumber + 1 AS sequance
FROM @t AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @t AS t2 ON t1.FileNumber + 1 = t2.FileNumber
WHERE t2.FileNumber IS NULL
```